# CKEditor5 wrap custom widget in a link, but prevent link clicks

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am trying to implement a custom widget plugin for CKEditor5, but am having hard time creating a widget that would prevent link clicks so that user stays on the same page and can edit the component itself.

I've initially started with this structure:

```
pluginWrapper > contentItemA + contentItemB + contentItemC
```

but although that mostly worked, balloons for that widget were misaligned. Meaning if I set a link it wrapped properly and link clicks actions were prevented, but the floating bar for link edit was misaligned as pluginWrapper was also positioned to "float: right";

So, I've tried to get some inspiration with a figure as e.g. visible here in the editor demo at the top of the page: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/images/images-overview.html

Here, if you set a link it works properly, including the balloons. Apparently because the figure is floating but all content is not. So I tried doing the same. Unfortunately unlike in the official example my link now became clickable when editing, which is far from desirable :(. And I can't prevent that with css to keep the content clickable and editable and my attempts in JS were not successful.

I was somehow hoping it does this automatically, either by the `evt.stop()` or `data.preventDefault()` here: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/blob/master/packages/ckeditor5-link/src/linkediting.js#L267 (definitely looks like it should), but it doesn't seem to like my plugin.

I have also tried doing something like that as part of my plugin, but that made no difference.

Either I am missing something or I am thinking I perhaps set the link up incorrectly. But if I omit that from my plugin and set the link up manually it still behaves this incorrect way :(.

However yes, this may not be the proper way to do this from the code, as I just add these attributes:

```
attributes: {
    linkHref: "https://www.xxx.zz",
    target: "_blank"
},
```

to the pluginWrapper (under `pluginTopWrapper > pluginWrapper`), and it ends up doing `pluginTopWrapper > a > pluginWrapper` with the a tag having the proper link, but seems to also ignore the target attribute :/. But I guess me being unable to set the link properly in code still doesn't explain why would the link be clickable when set up manually (using the link button in the editor toolbar) around my widget.

If you have any thoughts on this it would be very much appreciated. Thank you!